# Get a user from a message methode

Tags: discord-jda

I'm trying to make a discord bot with member activity, like, who many messages sent a user, but everytime I try to catch the user from message, to verify the activity, methode doesn't work. This is an example:

```
if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "testMention")) {
    if (event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().size() < 1) {
        canal.sendMessage("You don't mentioned any users").queue();
        return; 
    }

    User target = (User) event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0);
    canal.sendMessage("You've been mentioned " + target.getAsTag()).queue();
}
```

Comment: You have to be more specific than "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

Unless your prefix is the mention, your code can't work. If the message content equals for example `"!testMention"` then your first condition is true, the second condition `getMentionedMembers().size() < 1` has to be true in that case since your message content doesn't contain a mention.

You cannot cast a `Member` to `User` since these are completely different types. If you want to have a user then you need to use `getMentionedUsers()` instead or `member.getUser()`.